# Wrong Time Unit

Tags: java, android, background

I need may load at first bacground (setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo); ) after (6 second) Text in TextView4. but program make wrong. After start application, app wait 6 second and next build setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo); and write to TextView4

Why? 
Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(6);
        TextView textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textview4.setText("alalaalalalalalal");

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                   TextView textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textview4.setText("alalaalalalalalal");
            }
        }, 6000);
}
```

Comment: I copy your code and new Handler() is lined and .postDelayed is red. why?

Answer (score 0):

`sleep()` blocks the UI thread and your UI cannot draw itself.

Use e.g. a `Handler` and `postDelayed()` to post a `Runnable` to run at a later time without blocking the UI thread.